# Text Shadow with CSS Variable

Tags: css, shadow, alpha, rgba, css-variables

I have a problem with the text shadow property.

This works:

```
text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 var(--primary-color);
```

This doesn't work:

```
text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(var(--primary-color), 0.5);
```

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Thank you!

Comment: if the first one works, for sure it contains `rbg` so in the second case you will have a nested `rgb` thus it's invalid

Comment: The `color-mod` could have been a use case for this https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-4/#modifying-colors

Comment: The variable css is a hexadecimal code: `--primary-color: #f00`

Comment: so `rgba(#f00,0.5)` is also invalid

Comment: And how could I define the alpha channel from a hexadecimal variable?

Comment: @adrigm not. It would only be possible with color-mod

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```css
--primary-color: #f00;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 var(--primary-color);
text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(var(--primary-color), 0.5);
```

evaluates to

```css
text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #f00;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(#f00, 0.5);
```

`rgba(#f00, 0.5)` is not a valid rgba color.

Instead you could do:

```css
:root {
  --primary-color: 255, 0, 0;
}

.opaque {
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgb(var(--primary-color));
}

.translucent {
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(var(--primary-color), 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="opaque">Opaque</div>
<div class="translucent">Translucent</div>
```

Comment: Took me a minute to spot the difference, maybe state the change directly?